# my model function is returning nil, instead of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Heat, which has_many users

```
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  level      :string(255)
```

I want to define a method badge_level, which outputs a given string based on the Heat Id

```
  def badge_level
    "badge" # if id is 3, or nil 
    "badge badge-important" if self.id == 1
    "badge badge-warning" if self.id == 2
    "badge badge-info" if self.id == 4
    "badge badge-inverse" if self.id == 5
  end
```

But, when I run Heat.find(3).badge_level( or any id for that matter), I get nil as return.

Why, shouldn't I get "badge"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the the last line of a method is assumed `return` statement which in your case is `"badge badge-inverse" if self.id == 5`.  So if `self.id` is not `5` then your method will always return nil.

It looks like you want to return on every statement in that method.  I think `case...when` is more suitable for this case:

```
def badge_level
  case self.id
  when 1
    "badge badge-important"
  when 2
    "badge badge-warning"
  when 4
    "badge badge-info"
  when 5
    "badge badge-inverse"
  else
    "badge"
  end
end
```

With the updated `badge_level`, the `case...when` defaults to `badge` which is defined in the `else` block.  Note that `else` block will be executed for all other `self.id`s and `nil`.

One other possibility to check for `3` and `nil` in the `when` statement would be by replacing:

```
else
  "badge"
```

with:

```
when 3, nil
  "badge"
```

But I'm assuming you want `badge` to be defaulted to all other values including `3` and `nil`.